# Xcode 5.1.1 crash on starting

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I've just migrated from Xcode 5.0.2 to 5.1.1 and I'm always getting an exception just when the app is opening and I'm really puzzled with it because I don't know what's happening, I need that version of xcode to test with my device iphone 5s.

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Process:         Xcode [7340]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [333]
Responsible:     Xcode [7340]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-07-15 19:28:54.658 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  044342C4-F689-0487-D2A8-77FEE8704AB4

Sleep/Wake UUID: 0C4C242B-6F81-466E-A7E6-FF91D0887C3F

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: IDESourceControlTree Change Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-5074/DVTFoundation/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:254
Details:  <IDESourceControlRepository, 0x7fe39514ff20> was never invalidated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode's preferences and get rid of all repositories in the Accounts pane.

If that's not sufficient, you may have to take this project out of source control completely.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even open preferences panel, because indeed I wanted to try to unable all the respositories, but I can't even open that window.

Comment: @user3280424 Ooooh, yes, it all comes back to me now... I had this problem too... I think I had to quit Xcode, restart the computer, and then delete all of Xcode's preferences in order to make it "forget" everything so we could move forward.